# What is the difference between dig +tries=x and dig +retries=x?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dig

I have been looking at the dig documentation and don't understand the difference between dig +tries=x and dig +retries=x. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 1):

In cases like that, you might want to start by specifying which `dig` version you are talking about, to avoid any possible ambiguities.

In my version I have only `+tries` and `+retry` (note singular, not plural) and the manpage line on `+retry` specifically says something related to `+tries` which is:

> This option sets the number of times to retry UDP queries to server to T instead of the default, 2. Unlike +tries, this does not include the initial query.

If you study its source code, at https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/9c8b7a5c450d54332f25830aa47035d87490bb3a/bin/dig/dig.c for the latest version, you can see the truth even explained "simpler" than that (showing the two options act on the same variable in fact)

```
case 'r':
        switch (cmd[1]) {
[..]
        case 'e':
            switch (cmd[2]) {
[..]
            case 't': /* retry / retries */
[..]
                result = parse_uint(&lookup->retries, value,
                            MAXTRIES - 1, "retries");
                if (result != ISC_R_SUCCESS) {
                    warn("Couldn't parse retries");
                    goto exit_or_usage;
                }

                lookup->retries++;

[..]

case 't':
        switch (cmd[1]) {
[..]
        case 'r':
            switch (cmd[2]) {
[..]
            case 'i': /* tries */
[..]
                result = parse_uint(&lookup->retries, value,
                            MAXTRIES, "tries");
                if (result != ISC_R_SUCCESS) {
                    warn("Couldn't parse tries");
                    goto exit_or_usage;
                }
                if (lookup->retries == 0) {
                    lookup->retries = 1;
                }
                break;
```

So `retry` (or `retries` in fact) sets `lookup->retries` value and then increment it, while `tries` just sets the value to what was given. `tries` gives the total number of attempts to do, while `retry` gives the amount of attempts to do after a first failure, so the total amount of attempts is that plus one.
Same thing, just different API/semantic.

FWIW, `lookup->retries` is initialized elsewhere (before the above) like that:

```
int tries = 3;

[..]

    *looknew = (dig_lookup_t){
[..]
        .retries = tries,
```

That `3` explains the `2` in the man page as that `2` is the number of retries, so after the first try, hence total of tries by default would be 3. Yes, I do think all of this to be quite convoluted for something trivial :-)

Comment: Thanks! Very clear explanation.